# How do I break out of the loop on entering a null input

Tags: java

The following program is to display the word with maximum number of vowels.But it does not work until i have given 10 variables as input even though it is supposed to end after giving a null input.How can I fix this problem ( I already tried using different inputs like "." and "  ")

**

```
import java.util.*;
public class hw1{
public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        String w,temp="";
        int c=0,max=0;

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            w=sc.next();
            w=w.toUpperCase();
            if(w.equals(""))
            break;

            for(int j=0;j<w.length();j++)
            {
                if(w.charAt(j)=='A'||w.charAt(j)=='E'||w.charAt(j)=='I'||w.charAt(j)=='O'||w.charAt(j)=='U')
                c++;
            }
            max=Math.max(max,c);
            if(max==c)
            temp=w;
            c=0;
        }

        System.out.println(temp);
    }
}
```

**

Comment: Did you step through the code? What debugging steps have you taken?

Comment: What is `break` doing? What would happen if you used 2 loops instead of 1?

Comment: Tried using both while and do while loop.Also tried changing the break condition to check for a whitespace or fullstop

Comment: I am not sure if it is a preference but I would suggest you use `{}` after every if-statement to be sure what will be included in said if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
sc.next()
```

does not trigger if you give empty input (or press enter).
For allowing your exit condition to work you should use

```
w=sc.nextLine();
```

After that, if you hit enter, the for is broken and the app prints the result

Comment: It does work but then the output gives me the line with most vowels (if i enter more than one word as input)

Comment: You can get the line and then execute your loop on line.split(" ") to take single words and not the entire line